# Close fancybox from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a Fancybox that opens a contact form from an iframe. Inside the iframe, i have a close button but it's not working.

I have tryed both with `$.fancybox.close();` and `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to execute parent windows js function with different host name ( its not allowed ).
Try access you site without `www.` ( this is because your `contact` button using fancy from url without `www.` )

Answer (score 9):

As per http://fancybox.net/api Try this instead :

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: in case if you are using `jQuery.noConflict()` use `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()`